# Integral of $\sqrt{1+e^x}$, why does my method not work?

Tags: integration, trigonometric-integrals

What is the issue with my method, I make a substitution and get an integral in terms of $\theta$, then solve the integral, all of which is correct but the final answer is wrong, so am I not allowed to use $\tan \theta = e^{\frac{x}{2}}$ ? I only used this method because it works for other integrals similar to this one.

$\displaystyle\operatorname{Let} e^{\frac{x}{2}}=\tan \theta$. By pythagorean identities, $\displaystyle\cos \theta=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+e^x}} \implies \sec \theta=\sqrt{1+e^x}$
$$
\begin{aligned}
\\
& \frac{d}{d \theta}\left(\tan \theta=e^{\frac{x}{2}}\right)= \\
& \sec ^2 \theta=\frac{1}{2} e^{\frac{x}{2}} \frac{d x}{d \theta} \iff \frac{2 \sec^2 \theta}{\tan \theta} d \theta=d x \\
& \text{Then, }I = \int{\sqrt{1+e^x}}dx = 2 \int \sec ^3 \theta \cot \theta d \theta=2 \int \sec ^2 \theta \csc \theta d \theta \\
& =2\sec \theta-2 \ln |\csc \theta+\cot \theta|+C \\
& \quad \\
& \sec \theta=\sqrt{1+e^2} \implies \csc \theta=\frac{\sqrt{1+e^x}}{e^{\frac{x}{2}}}, \, \quad \tan\theta = e^{\frac{x}{2}} \implies \cot \theta=\frac{1}{e^{\frac{x}{2}}} \\
& \therefore I=2 \sqrt{1+e^x}-2 \ln \left(\frac{1+\sqrt{1+e^x}}{e^{\frac{x}{2}}}\right)+C \\
& =2 \sqrt{1+e^x}+x-\ln \left(1+\sqrt{1+e^x}\right)^2+C \\
&
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: If I were to guess, you're using an answer key to check your answers, and your answer doesn't "look like" the answer there.  Is that right?

Comment: It seems I got it completely wrong according to integral calc online

Comment: @beefsniffer19, your result is absolutely correct

Comment: It would appear I made a blunder in assuming I got it wrong. Apparently its right, just the answer sheet gives the answer in a different form, as do integral calculators! My bad

Comment: There are a couple mistaken assumptions students often make.  The first is that every function can only be written in one way.  The second is that if $F(x)+C$ is an indefinite integral and $G(x)+C$ is an indefinite integral, then $F(x)=G(x)$.  Both are errors that show up in comparing answers, but I don't know which you made.

Comment: Step 1: Render the book's answer. Step 2: Check whether it actually differs from yours by just a constant. If Step 2 turns out true, you and the book are actually agreeing because of the constant of integration.

Comment: Also, you're free to use whichever substitution you want. You could let $x = \sin(\cos(u))$ or $\theta = \frac{x}{x^2+\sin(x)}$ and the work would be valid as long as your equalities hold true, but the bigger question should be whether or not using some so-and-so substitution is helpful.

Comment: Did you misplace the $2$ and put it outside the logarithm instead of inside? The final answer should be $2\sqrt{1+e^{x}}+x-2\ln\left(1+\sqrt{1+e^{x}}\right)+C$.

Comment: I think my answer works I checked by differentiating it, but thanks for the tip about substitution! Useful tool to have in my toolkit for sure

Comment: @Accelerator i took the power of two into the logarithm but could have left the two on the outside like u did which looks cleaner, we both get the same end result I believe. I just wrote ln(u^2) rather than write 2lnu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@beefsniffer19, you are correct and well-done. I have another solution for your confirmation.
$$
\begin{aligned}
I & =\int \frac{1+e^x}{\sqrt{1+e^x}} d x \\
& =2 \int \frac{1+e^x}{e^x} d\left(\sqrt{1+e^x}\right) \\
& =2 \int \frac{d (\sqrt{1+e^x})}{e^x}+2 \int d\left(\sqrt{1+e^x}\right) \\
& =2 \int \frac{d (\sqrt{1+e^x})}{\left(\sqrt{1+e^x}\right)^2-1}+2 \sqrt{1+e^x}\\&= \ln \left|\frac{\sqrt{1+e^x}-1}{\sqrt{1+e^x}+1}\right|+2 \sqrt{1+e^x}+C\\&= x-2 \ln \left(1+\sqrt{1+e^x}\right)+2 \sqrt{1+e^x}+C \\ 
\end{aligned}
$$

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: Your answer is correct.

If you want more details, you need to explain *why you think* it's incorrect.  Those details are currently lacking.

Comment: This looks more like a comment than an answer.

Comment: @AnneBauval The first part is an answer.  The latter part could be folded into a comment by itself, but is also appropriate to explain the shortness of an answer.  It answers the only question, so it's inappropriate as a comment.  The only alternatives I can see are to delete the question (which I'm fine with) or to impose some arbitrary minimum padding for answer length (which is absurd)